# How to use (call) a variable from a function (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to program a character (perso) who moves in a map generates with an Array.
There my variable "t" who call my "Tuiles" MovieClip, creating a grid (grille) with new tile each "1" on my "map" Array.
I first fixed collision function with one tile Child, so, I created "map" and "grid" functions. I need "t" variable for the world creat AND the character collision.
If I put variable on my function "creeDecor", Flash generates it good but saying me variable "t" doesn't exist for my collision function.
If I put "t" variable on top of my code as a general variable, Flash generates one tile on right-bottom of stage with collision function working good...

How could I mix them twice ?
Is it possible ?

I let you my entire code. If you want it to work you just have to create a MovieClip class name "Tuiles" (square : 32*32) and a second MC "Perso".

```
//Creation of perso

var perso:Perso = new Perso();

var grille:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

var t:Tuiles = new Tuiles();

var T:int = 32;



var map:Array = [

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],

                 ]



// temporary stockage

var stock:Array = [

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],

                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

                 ]



creeDecor()                                                                        

initHero();




stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, clavierDown);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, clavierUp);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animation);



// Stage collision

var minX = 0;

var minY = 0;

var maxX = stage.stageWidth - perso.width;

var maxY = stage.stageHeight - perso.height;

var speedHero = 5;



function clavierDown(e)

{

    switch(e.keyCode)

    {  

        case 37:

            perso.speedX = -speedHero;

            break;

        case 39:

            perso.speedX = speedHero;

            break;

        case 38:

            perso.speedY = -speedHero;

            break;

        case 40:

            perso.speedY = speedHero;

            break;

}

}



function clavierUp(e)

{

    switch(e.keyCode)

    {

        case 37:

            perso.speedX = 0;

            break; 



        case 39:

            perso.speedX = 0;

            break;



        case 38:

            perso.speedY = 0;

            break;



            case 40:

            perso.speedY = 0;

            break;

    }

}



function animation(e)

{

    animeHero();

}

   // Stage border collision function

function animeHero()

{       

       if(perso.x + perso.speedX >= minX && perso.x + perso.speedX <= maxX)

   {

       perso.x += perso.speedX;

   } else if (perso.speedX < 0)

   {

       perso.x -= Math.abs(perso.x-minX);

               //trace(Math.abs(perso.x-minX));

   } else {

       perso.x += Math.abs(perso.x-maxX) ;

   }



   if(perso.y + perso.speedY >= minY && perso.y + perso.speedY <= maxY)

   {

       perso.y += perso.speedY;

   }

  collision();

}



function initHero()

{

    perso.speedX = 0;

    perso.speedY = 0;



    perso.x = 200;

    perso.y = 300;


    addChild(perso);

}



function collision() {



    if (perso.hitTestObject(t))

    {

        if (perso.x >= t.x + t.width - speedHero && perso.x <= t.x +t.width + 2)

        {

            perso.x = t.x + t.width;

        }



        if (perso.x + perso.width >= t.x - 2 && perso.x + perso.width <= t.x + speedHero)

        {

            perso.x = t.x - perso.width;

        }

        if (perso.y >= t.y + t.height - speedHero && perso.y <= t.y +t.height + 2)

        {

            perso.y = t.y + t.height;

        }



        if (perso.y + perso.height >= t.y - 2 && perso.y + perso.height <= t.y + speedHero)

        {

            perso.y = t.y - perso.height;

        }

    }

}



// level creation

function creeDecor():void{

    for (var i:int=0; i<20; i++){                                // boucle sur les 20 colonnes

        for (var j:int=0; j<15; j++){                            // boucle sur les 15 lignes de chaque colonne

            var f:int = map[j][i] 



            if(f>0)  {     
                t.x= i*T;  

                t.y= j*T;  

                t.gotoAndStop(f)             

                grille.addChild(t)         


                // Specialisation

                if (f==1)

                stock[j][i] = t;

            }



            else

            {

                stock[j][i] = []                               

            }

        }

    }

}

addChild(grille)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make lots of different `Tuiles` and also check collisions with every one of them. It sounds like you were making new `Tuiles` in `creeDecor()` originally, but unless you store the new tiles outside of that, only `creeDecor()` knows about them. (That's why Flash said `t` didn't exist in `collision()`.) [This page about Function scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html) might help, as well as the rest of that document in general if you haven't read it yet.

So, you might prepare a list of all of your `Tuiles` at the top level, like:

```
var tList:Vector.<Tuiles> = new Vector.<Tuiles>();
```

That means that both `creeDecor()` and `collision()` can see `tList`. Then as you did before, make new `Tuiles` in `creeDecor()` each time you need one, and **add them to the list**:

```
if(f>0)  {
    var newT:Tuiles = new Tuiles();
    tList.push(newT);
    // Set up newT's position etc...
```

Then, you can run your hit test for every `Tuiles` in `tList` using ["for each... in"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for_each..in)

```
for each (var t:Tuiles in tList) {
    if (perso.hitTestObject(t))
        // Your collision code...
    }
}
```

If you only have simple squares, there are probably faster ways of doing collision detection than using `hitTestObject` lots of times, so adjusting that might be a good next step if it's slow.

Comment: I'd like to ask you which way could I take to generate several reactions for several tile frames ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, but have you made a custom class for `Tuiles`, or is it just a MovieClip automatically exported from the library? You could write your own functions in `Tuiles.as` to do what you need. (eg. http://www.flashandmath.com/bridge/intro/index.html)

Comment: No, it's just a MovieClip from Library ! Okay ! Thanks again David